# WordPress блог и остальной сайт на разных поддоменах

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Сайт WordPress на mydomain.com

Хочу посадить блог на blog.mydomain.com

Сделал запись НС ´*´

Теперь перенаправляет на главную. Что в htaccess прописать, чтобы  mydomain.com/blog  стало blog.mydomain.com?

Comment: Что такое  "blog" в сущностьях ВП?

Answer (score 0):

С помощю `.htaccess` редирект делается вот так:

Первый вариант самый простой:

```
Redirect 301 /blog http://blog.mydomain.com
```

Второй вариант:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^/blog(/.*)?$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://blog.mydomain.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

И еще обратите внимание что если делать редирект `301` это постоянный редирект, а если хотите временный то надо вместо `301` написать `302`.

Подробно про типов редиректов можете прочитать [здесь](http://www.rodinalinkov.ru/blog/2015/01/10/301-ili-302-redirekt/#.WUztW3Xyg8o).

Comment: с ВП так делать нельзя!